# Code Cleanup in Visual Studio 2022 For One Solution Only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-cleanup

I have some separated solutions in my hard disk.
And I have configured my Visual Studio 2022 like this:
[image]

But one of them (the oldest one) does not follow the configuration. This is what happens, after applying Code Clean-up, even if the method was expression-bodied:

[image]

Note: **I have not .editorconfig in solution folder (in hard and solution explorer)**

I want my solution to follow my configuration as the other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why is that happening. Actually I don't know why. But now, I know how to fix it. All I had to do was commenting the following line in `.csproj` file:

```
<!--<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>-->
```

And done!!!